# ESP32 - SIM800 - HTTPS lwIP

Tags: esp32, http, esp, sim800

I am using ESP32 and SIM800L for my project. The SIM800L does support SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1. But web servers nowadays usually support only TLS 1.2 and 1.3. I heard, that the ESP32 HTTPS client can use lwIP stack from other libraries. Is there some way to implement the lwIP? Is there some other way to get TLS 1.2 and 1.3 working?

Comment: it is not possible to make SIM800 work with LwIP.

Comment: @Juraj And is there any other way to get TLS 1.2 and 1.3 work on SIM800L?

Comment: Some, but not all, versions of the SIM800 support SSL. Having SSL support depends on the firmware version and the individual module. Users have had varying levels of success in using SSL on the SIM800 even with apparently identical firmware. If you need SSL and it does not appear to be working on your SIM800, try a different module or get a newer SIMCOM module than SIM800(they are really old that no longer in prouduction).